# Why doesn't jQuery Tiny Scrollbar work correctly in IE7?

Tags: jquery

I am working on a very small site and have been asked to use scrollbars to display the content in the pages: http://discovermonroeville.com/literary-heritage

I found this handy jQuery plugin: http://baijs.nl/tinyscrollbar/

The plugin works great in everything except IE7, but for some reason it does not scroll in IE7.

Here is the code:

```
<div id="scrollbar1">
  <div class="scrollbar"><div class="track"><div class="thumb"><div class="end"></div></div></div></div>
    <div class="viewport">
         <div class="overview">             
            <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Ut vitae velit at velit pretium sodales. Maecenas egestas imperdiet mauris, vel elementum turpis iaculis eu. Duis egestas augue quis ante ornare eu tincidunt magna interdum. Vestibulum posuere risus non ipsum sollicitudin quis viverra ante feugiat. Pellentesque non faucibus lorem. Nunc tincidunt diam nec risus ornare quis porttitor enim pretium. Ut adipiscing tempor massa, a ullamcorper massa bibendum at. Suspendisse potenti. In vestibulum enim orci, nec consequat turpis. Suspendisse sit amet tellus a quam volutpat porta. Mauris ornare augue ut diam tincidunt elementum. Vivamus commodo dapibus est, a gravida lorem pharetra eu. Maecenas ultrices cursus tellus sed congue. Cras nec nulla erat.</p>                   
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Any clues as to why it will not scroll in IE7? Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like it could potentially be a javascript error. Remove the ',' after delay: 1000.

```
        $(document).ready(function() {
$('.slideshow').cycle({
        fx: 'fade',
        speed: 6000,
        delay:  1000,
        });
        $('#scrollbar1').tinyscrollbar();
```

Comment: Thank you very much for taking the time to look so carefully at the code. I see a great future ahead for you on Stackoverflow.

Comment: No worries, thank you. It was a simple case of checking the console tab within IE developer tools. ;)

Comment: IE is stricter with trailing `,` characters, which are not allowed in some versions of the JavaScript specification but are now no an error in newer versions

Comment: Very true, browsers are much more lenient these days.

Answer (score 0):

Re-init your scroll then it will work fine.....

```
$('#scrollbar1').tinyscrollbar_update();
```